# can we exit without error from telnet with MozRepl?

Tags: error-handling, telnet, exit, mozrepl

based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138354/30352), I am trying to figure out a way to exit from telnet and it return 0

these wont work:

```
(echo -e "repl.quit()";sleep 1) |telnet localhost 4242;echo $?
(echo -e "\029";sleep 1;echo "q";sleep 1) |telnet localhost 4242;echo $?
(echo -e "\c]";sleep 1;echo "q";sleep 1) |telnet localhost 4242;echo $?
(echo -e "\e]";sleep 1;echo "q";sleep 1) |telnet localhost 4242;echo $?
(echo -e "\E]";sleep 1;echo "q";sleep 1) |telnet localhost 4242;echo $?
```

The problem is: I am UNABLE to differentiate from a successful exit and a failed one...

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681683/cant-close-a-scpitelnet-session-with-echo-when-i-use-it-in-a-script) can be linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send `^]` character, that is an unprintable group separator character before your telnet client terminates your connection after executing all commands you gave it via pipe. Most versions of `echo` program can produce unprintable characters using `-e` option. Group separator is 035 in octal (you can see the entire ASCII table with `man 7 ascii` on *nix systems.). So, the entire command should look like this:

```
$ (echo "content.location.href = 'http://v4.ident.me/'"; sleep 2; echo -e '\035'; sleep 2) | telnet localhost 4242 > /dev/null
$ echo $?
$ 0
```

Comment: `\035` !!!, I only got a tip to `\029` which did not work, thx!! btw, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681683/cant-close-a-scpitelnet-session-with-echo-when-i-use-it-in-a-script) I think you may be able to answer it by just linking to your answer here, you can grab its link on the 'share' that is just below the text!

Comment: it required another delay between url and echo here to work; the `man -7 ascii` is very useful too thx!

Comment: I just found (quick looking on the result) that `man ascii` == `man -7 ascii` == `man 7 ascii`, it seems to ignore the 7 part :)

Comment: It is not ignored. It just happened that you have only one manpage titled `ascii` on your machine - in this case `7` is redundant because always manpage from the 7th section of the manual will be opened. However, I got used to `man 7 ascii` command when I want to see an ASCII table because I remember I used some systems with multiple manpages titled `ascii` installed in different sections of the manual on which `man ascii` would open manpage from an incorrect section.